# What are the blue "stars"?

Tags: star, galaxy, identify-this-object

From NASA September 16 [Hubble studies a spectacular spiral](https://www.nasa.gov/image-feature/goddard/2022/hubble-studies-a-spectacular-spiral):

[image]

There are 4 really bright blue stars in this photo of galaxy NGC 1961. For those who can't see them very clearly, you can focus on the furthest top right one.

Is it a type O star as its blue? They seem much brighter than any other stars and are further away from the galaxy too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is almost certainly a foreground star.

It appears in the [Gaia database as source 485036192954347136](https://aladin.unistra.fr/AladinLite/?target=05%2041%2049.728%2B69%2023%2027.16&fov=0.13&survey=CDS%2FP%2FDSS2%2Fcolor) and is given a parallax of 0.49 milliarcseconds, corresponding to a distance of 2000 parsecs (6500 light years). A long way, but still firmly in the milkyway.

It is not part of the NGC 1961

I can't find a spectral type for this object, but in the DSS images it is brighter in the red filter than in the blue one, suggesting it is a more likely to be a (perhaps) F or A type dwarf than a very powerful O type star.  That would be consistent with its apparent magnitude and distance too.  (2Mass gives a magnitude of about 13.5, suggesting an absolute magnitude of about 2)

Comment: "This is almost certainly a foreground star", how about the other similar looking stars closer to the galaxy?

Comment: Yes, those too, for the same reasons. You can check on Aladin for the parallax of each source.